# Woocommerce Pricing Calculator

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using the following two plugins that i need to modify to achieve my next goal.

Woocommerce &
Woocommerce Cost Of Product

Ok so i am able to set pricing discount in woocommerce but what i want to do is the opposite and create an extension where i can a percentage to the price of all categories added ontop of the cost value of the products. A new page template would be handy to display all product categories with an imput field aside of the label to enter the % i require to be calculated to the cost price.

i am using the Woocommerce cost of products to produce a price on the fly( this is because my cost prices change daily and generate quotes rather than displaying product prices ) so what i need to do once the fields are setup to add the % profit to the cost price is calculate it dynamically when i enter the cost price in the Woocommerce cost of goods field, this will give me a true total of price to sell the product at and its quantities.

An example would be:

> 1 Box of Eggs ( cost £1.00 ) + (20% ( set in the new category price field ) * quantity ) total £1.20 when calculated in cost of goods order process

Comment: Perhaps move this question to [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)? Other than that - I'm afraid you're going to have to read the woocommerce plugin source code to find the correct hooks to override price calculation. It's tricky.

Comment: You've posted your solution in your question? Just use the formula you posted above and make the calculation.

Comment: Kenney, it will get closed at the WordPress stack exchange since it is not specifically about WordPress core. This kind of sounds like the type of project you might need a developer for.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, what i'm probably best doing is paying for someone to make the modifications for me then i can post the results here for anyone else wanting it in future

Comment: you need to use this hook to set price in woo commerce. I user this in my woocommerce custom plugin like price calc. add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html', array($this, 'wcu_price_per_unit_html'), 10, 2);
   add_filter('woocommerce_price_html', array($this, 'wcu_price_per_unit_html'), 10, 2);
   add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', array($this, 'wcu_price_per_unit_html'), 10, 2);